# Why do we need >= 95% throughput for LTE Sensitivity measurement according to 3GPP

Tags: signal-detection, lte

According to 3GPP 36 series for LTE, for LTE Sensitivity measurements we need >=95% throughput. How is this 95% value determined? Why it is not 98% or 88%.

Answer (score 1):

It's a definition. There's probably no specific reason
other than "the committee agreed on it".

Point is: this is for comparability of other tests. So, the actual number 95% is less important than that all use the same.